Kotlin Multiplatform: composeApp:wasmJsMain: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.compose.html:html-core:1.6.11
I am trying to include the following dependency (org.jetbrains.compose.html:html-core:1.6.11) into my build.gradle.kts file under composeMain so i can use the Video Composable to load a video on my webapp. However, I get the following error when syncing:
:composeApp:wasmJsMain: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.compose.html:html-core:1.6.11.
Required by:
    project :composeApp

I have tried adding this dependency using wasmJsMain however same error.
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.dsl.ExperimentalWasmDsl
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackConfig

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}

kotlin {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalWasmDsl::class)
    wasmJs {
        moduleName = "composeApp"
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                outputFileName = "composeApp.js"
                devServer = (devServer ?: KotlinWebpackConfig.DevServer()).apply {
                    static = (static ?: mutableListOf()).apply {
                        // Serve sources to debug inside browser
                        add(project.projectDir.path)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
    
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(projects.shared)
            implementation("org.jetbrains.compose.html:html-core:1.6.11")
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "org.suite.app"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "org.suite.app"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
    }
}


I think "org.jetbrains.compose.html:html-core" dependency should be in jsMain, not commonMain

Yea It did work for jsMain but what i realized is that the project is configured for wasm, i didnt know there was a compose html and compose wasm

yes, compose html was originally introduced - it allows building html in compose style, but it's impossible to share any elements. compose wasm draws on canvas, so it allows using all components shared with kotlin multiplatform

How would i go about playing a video which was my original task. I just started working with KMP today, so what I am trying now is the following:
val video = document.createElement("video") as HTMLVideoElement
